# Sum of list item value in GenericList in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have generic list -GasPropList - in that i want the sum of the all individual items value.
All Varaibles are in Double datatype.

```
For Each gasprop In GasPropList
            gasprop.OUTGi = gasprop.NameVal * gasprop.GasGi / 100
            gasprop.OUTPci = gasprop.NameVal * gasprop.Pci / 100
            gasprop.OUTTci = gasprop.NameVal * gasprop.Tci / 100
            gasprop.OUTVi = gasprop.NameVal * gasprop.NHVi / 100
            gasprop.OUTGVi = gasprop.NameVal * gasprop.GHDVi / 100
        Next
```

From this i want to calculate sum of OUTGi, OUTPi etc.
I saw Linq Sum function, but don't know how to use for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E.g.

```
Dim OUTGiSum = GasPropList.Sum(Function(gp) gp.OUTGi)
```

I'll leave it to you to do the others.

Comment: My class and List are very similar to the above example, but I keep getting "Sum is not a member of System.Collection.Generic.List"

Comment: @Macromika, `Sum` is an extension method and actually a member of the `Enumerable` class.  See the relevant doco [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2).  You have to have imported the appropriate namespace to be able to access members of that class, although that is usually done by default these days.